# show value from text..if delimited by ; show only first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table with values. It is ntext because of ; delimited. Values can be empty, 1 number and numbers delimited by semicolon (as shown)

```
+-----------+
|   room    |
+-----------+
|    64     |
+-----------+
|   60008   |
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
| 127;50047 |
+-----------+
```

I have this code. Substring is looking for ; and show first value. It is working only where the values are delimited. So how can I change it, that it will show first value when ; and single value also. So from table bellow I will get `64,60008, ,127`.

```
SELECT  
T0.U_Scid as 'id',
T3.U_Boarding as 'start',
T3.U_Boarding as 'end',

SUBSTRING(T5.U_Partner, 0, CHARINDEX(';', T5.U_Partner)) AS 'room_id',

CASE WHEN datalength(T5.U_Partner)=0 THEN '9999' ELSE T5.U_Partner END  AS 'room_id' , 
CASE WHEN datalength(T5.U_Partner) > 4 THEN T5.U_Partner ELSE '9999' END AS 'partners_id' ,
```

This is just bonus question. CASE are looking for length of value, if the value is longer than 4 ( 600008 ) write to room_id 9999 and save 600008 to partners_id. If it is empty write 9999 to room_id.

How to make it works together?.so getting value from T_Partner..save it into temporary table T1.TempRoom ( I suppose ).. so T1.TempRoom (is filled with numbers like 64, ,60008,127) then CASE is checking T1.TempRoom for values and save it into room_id and partners_id.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple method:

```
SUBSTRING(T5.U_Partner, 1, CHARINDEX(';', T5.U_Partner + ';')) AS room_id,
```

That is, concatenate the semicolon to the argument for `CHARINDEX()`.  That will prevent any error occurring.

In addition, indexing for `SUBSTRING()` starts at 1, not 0.

And, don't use single quotes for column names.  Only use them for string and date literals.

EDIT:

You can always use the verbose form:

```
(CASE WHEN T5.U_Partner LIKE '%;%'
      THEN SUBSTRING(T5.U_Partner, 1, CHARINDEX(';', T5.U_Partner + ';'))
      ELSE T5.U_Partner
 END) AS room_id
```

Comment: The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @Burco . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation as well as addition.

Comment: I know..but I am getting this error message. When I delete + ';' everything is working like before . So show only values from text where numbers are delimited..not single values

Comment: Then use `N';'`, although I'm surprised that would be necessary.  You could also use `CONCAT(T5.U_Partner, ';')`.

Comment: CASE was giving me: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Now I try to run CONCAT

Comment: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the concat operation. I was checking this error

Comment: @Burco . . . You are using strange collations -- the default collation is different from the column collation.  Use the `COLLATE` keyword for `';'`, so the collations are the same.

Comment: Thanks for help..but still no change

Comment: I was playing with it ..and now it is working. How about the bonus question..Is it the right way?